# JSON Schema check entire json for certain property with null values

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm trying to write a json schema that searches any json with different structures for all occurences of a certain property called "field_name" and checks if that property has a value. There can't be an empty "field_name".

The property "field_name" can be at any level in the json file, e.g

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stopopol/deims_apps/master/metadata_models/smm.json

So far I have this, but it never complains when a "field_name" is empty.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "title": "Metadata Model",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "name",
    "abbreviation",
    "version",
    "releaseDate",
    "scope",
    "content"
  ],
  "patternProperties": {
    "field_name": {
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 1
    }
  }
}
```

I thought that I could just check for any occurence of property "field_name" and that it needs to be a string with a lenght of at least 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a surprisingly simple recursive schema. The `properties` and `additionalProperties` keywords only apply when the data being validated is an object. If the data is not an object, these keywords get ignored. This allows us to express the "if the value is an object" part simply by leaving out the `"type": "object"` declaration.

The use of `allOf`/`definitions` shows how to express the recursive constraint without making the entire schema recursive.

```
{
  "title": "Metadata Model",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "name",
    "abbreviation",
    "version",
    "releaseDate",
    "scope",
    "content"
  ],
  "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/field_name-not-empty-deep" }],
  "definitions": {
    "field_name-not-empty-deep": {
      "properties": {
        "field_name": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": { "$ref": "#/definitions/field_name-not-empty-deep" }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution. The answer provided by @CalmDownVal actually caused additional schema violations, but this one applies cleanly and does exactly what I need.

Comment: It can even be easiliy extended to check for additional empty fields. It's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "anyOf" :
    [
        {
            "not" :
            {
                "type" : "object"
            }
        },
        {
            "properties" :
            {
                "field_name" :
                {
                    "not" :
                    {
                        "type" : "null"
                    }
                }
            },
            "additionalProperties" :
            {
                "$ref" : "#"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Each instance encountered is either not an object OR it checks for your property not being null, then it runs the filter on all other properties (this is done using the $ref which points to the root object) in turn applying this recursively on all possible sub-objects.

(I assume by "empty" you mean the property is set and equal to null.)